# How to change specific menu tab from left to right in My Home Theme?

Tags: css

may i know is there any css that i can use it to change the specific menu tab from left to right?
i would like to change the language tab and profile tab (with it sub menu) from left to right.
And the theme that i had use for my wordpress is MyHomeTheme. [image]

Comment: Login into your dashboard, got to **Appearance>>Menu** select the menu that has these menu links and switch positions.

Comment: i had try. But it only move the position for the tab (e.g. the first tab change to the second tab)  and not tht can be move the tab from left side to right side.

Comment: Are you referring to down caret shown for the item with sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

> take reference of two classes and apply css
>   e.g you have menu in li as:

```
<li class="menu-item-24011">
<span class="menu-text">profile</span>
</li>
```

> then add this css:

```
.menu-item-24011 .menu-text {
padding-left: 50%;//change as per your req
```

}